# Definite Integral of an Infinite Sum

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions

It is given that $$ f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(nx)}{4^n} $$

How would one go about calculating $$ \int_0^\pi f(x)\ dx $$

EDIT:

I was able to calculate the integral of the $ \sin(nx) $ part using $u$ substitution. However, I lack the required knowledge to combine an integral and an infinite sum as this is the first time  I am doing this kind of a question.

I am currently studying in 11th in India under the CBSE curriculum. This question appeared in one of my internal tests and I am trying to get an explanation for it.

I'd like to mention that I only posess basic knowledge of integration and differentiation as taught in my coaching center and knowledge of 11th grade NCERT math.

Comment: Note that $-1\leq \sin(nx) \leq 1,$ for all $n$.

Comment: @amWhy Yes I am aware of the range of the sin function. Could you please explain how does that help with the question?

Comment: I see that the Indian educational system loves acronyms! :-)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since the series converges uniformly, we can integrate term-wise. The result is

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\pi} f(x) \, dx
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{4^n} \int_{0}^{\pi} \sin(nx) \, dx \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{4^n} \left[ -\frac{\cos (nx)}{n} \right]_{0}^{\pi} \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1 - (-1)^n}{n \cdot4^n}.
\end{align*}

Now using the Taylor expansion $\log(1+x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n} x^n$, we can simplify the above series as

$$ = - \log\left(1 - \tfrac{1}{4}\right) + \log\left(1 + \tfrac{1}{4}\right)
 = \log \left( \tfrac{5}{3} \right). $$

---

Alternatively, assuming basic knowledge on complex analysis,

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\pi} f(x) \, dx
&= \operatorname{Im} \left( \int_{0}^{\pi} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{e^{ix}}{4} \right)^n \, dx \right)
 = \operatorname{Im} \left( \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{e^{ix}}{4 - e^{ix}} \, dx \right) \\
(z=e^{ix}) \quad &= \operatorname{Im} \left( \int_{1}^{-1} \frac{1}{i(4-z)} \, dz \right)
 = \operatorname{Im} \left[ i \log(4-z) \right]_{1}^{-1} \\
&= \log 5 - \log 3
 = \log (5/3).
\end{align*}

This provides a natural explanation as to why logarithm appears in the final answer.

Comment: Could you please shed more light on how the last step goes from an infinite sum to a natural log? I have heard of the Taylor Expansion of log(1+x). Thanks

Comment: @Tusky, If you successfully obtained the series expression in the last line, then you are almost done. Just split this into two parts $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1 - (-1)^n}{n \cdot4^n} = -\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}\left(-\frac{1}{4}\right)^n + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^n $$ and apply the Taylor series of $\log(1+x)$ separately. (Notice how I created the factor $(-1)^{n-1}$ to match the formula of $\log(1+x)$.) Or, you may first observe that the Taylor series of $\log(1-x)$ is $-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}x^n$ and then proceed.

Comment: Ah that makes things much more clear to me now. Thanks! Do you have any tips for me as a student to be able to crack these kinds of problems and improve my ability overall?

Comment: @Tusky, To be honest I have no good idea. I mostly followed the regular curriculum of my university...

Comment: Hey I was going over the steps again and I had a minor doubt. Could you please explain why the $ \frac{1}{4^{n}} $ comes out of the integral but not the $ \sin{nx} $? What is the criteria for an expression being eligible for swapping the integral and summation and what terms can you bring out of the summation?

Comment: @Tusky, Recall that integral satisfies linearity: if $f, g$ are integrable functions on $[a, b]$ and $\alpha, \beta$ are constants, then $$\int_{a}^{b}(\alpha f(x)+\beta g(x))\,dx = \alpha \int_{a}^{b} f(x) \, dx + \beta \int_{a}^{b} g(x) \, dx. $$ So you can freely move constants in and out of integrals. (More precisely anything that does not depend on the variable of integration can be moved so.) This is an exact analogue to the case of summation, where $$\sum_k \alpha f(k) = \alpha \sum_k f(k) $$ is valid (distributivity!), but it is absurd to pull $f(k)$ out of the summation.

Comment: Ah, so when you're integrating with respect to $ dx $, you're taking your $ \frac{1}{4^{n}} $ as a constant term. Got it.

Comment: @Tusky, That's right. You may convince yourself by recalling that integral is defined as a limit of certain sum, hence it will inherit most properties of sum as well (such as distributive property of multiplication over addition, which manifests as linearity as I mentioned above).

Comment: Hey so I was going over a little bit of complex analysis recently and I saw that you made the substitution $ z = e^{ix} $ from $1$ to $-1$. I was just wondering why you didn't specify the curve along which you are integrating, like the path because I read that you can go from a point in the complex plane to another one in different ways. Do you have to make it a contour integral? Or am I just over-complicating stuff? I'm sorry but I'm really trying my best to understand this stuff and you were the most helpful person I came across by far.

Comment: @Tusky, You have a valid point. In fact, just writing $\int_{1}^{-1}\cdots$ is a lazy notation, and it is really intended as a contour integral along the semicircular contour $t \mapsto e^{it}$ for $0 \leq t \leq \pi$. But this ambiguity is not a big issue, as we have an analogue of the fundamental theorem of calculus for contour integrals as well, and I utilized the fact that $\frac{1}{4-z}$ has antiderivative $-\log(4-z)$ on $\mathbb{C}\setminus[4,\infty)$ where $\log$ is the principal logarithm.

Comment: Oh right. So if I say that for every single integral in the complex plane and generally for an integral involving more than 1 variable in the real and complex numbers domain, that is necessary to specify the path along which you are integrating without which the integral calls for speculation as to which path you are traversing to go from say $a$ to $b$?

Answer (score 10):

An alternative approach:
$$ f(x)=\text{Im}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{e^{inx}}{4^n} = \text{Im}\left(\frac{e^{ix}}{4-e^{ix}}\right) = \text{Im}\left(\frac{e^{ix}(4-e^{-ix})}{17-8\cos x}\right)=\frac{4\sin x}{17-8\cos x}$$
implies:
$$ \int_{0}^{\pi}f(x)\,dx=\left[\tfrac{1}{2}\,\log(17-8\cos x)\right]_{0}^{\pi}=\log\sqrt{\frac{17+8}{17-8}}=\color{red}{\log\tfrac{5}{3}}. $$

Comment: I saw this question earlier today and put it in my reading list because I knew it was right up your alley and I wanted to see your approach once you got around to if!

Comment: Hey Jack, thanks for taking the time to answer my question. Could you please explain how you go from step 2 to step 3? How do you get a $ (4-e^{-ix}) $ in the numerator and $ 17 - 8 \cos{x} $ in the denominator?

Comment: @Tusky: rationalization: by multiplying $4-e^{ix}$ by $4-e^{-ix}$ we get $4^2+1-4e^{ix}-4e^{-ix}=17-8\cos x$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Ah it makes sense now. Although could you please explain the reason behind multiplying by $ 4 -  e^{-ix} $ instead of multiplying by $ 4 + e^{ix} $ and then applying $ (a+b)(a-b) = a^{2} - b^{2} $ ?

Comment: @Tusky: in order to extract the imaginary part of a ratio, it is more practical to make the denominator a real number, by multiplying both the numerator and the denominator by the *conjugate* of the denominator.